# How can I send e-mail from oracle command?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try create file from pl/sql,
I exported the data and I need email it,
A good way was to do it in .net console that call my sql code and send an email,
but can I send the email from sql and that's it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the utl_mail package. Documentation is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/arpls/UTL_MAIL.html#GUID-47AE34E9-3123-4115-AC86-4FF538DBFBBB).